# Excel SUM vs. Numpy SUM // different outputs?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here i have four small numbers:

```
0.0132391039
0.0097909093
-0.0028579101
0.0245043133
```

If i would sum them with excel or calculator, output would be:

```
0.0446764164
```

But if I would sum this numbers with numpy array:

```
print np.sum(np.array([0.0132391039, 0.0132391039, -0.0028579101, 0.0245043133]))
```

Output would be:

```
0.048124611
```

Why am i having such difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
print numpy.sum(numpy.array([0.0132391039, 0.0097909093, -0.0028579101, 0.0245043133]))
```

instead of

```
print numpy.sum(numpy.array([0.0132391039, 0.0132391039, -0.0028579101, 0.0245043133]))
```

(look at the second number)

first result: 0.0446764164

second:       0.048124611

(perfectly reproducing your error)

Answer (score 4):

You have different values

```
 0.0132391039
 0.0097909093 # different
-0.0028579101
 0.0245043133


[0.0132391039, 0.0132391039, -0.0028579101, 0.0245043133]
               # different
```